# Sql query returns only first row

Tags: php, mysql

I'm try to display a result of a select query, but i only get duplicate first row not all the rows.  here is my code :

```
$query = "SELECT Email from client";
$result = $db->query($query)->fetch();
foreach($result as $email){
    echo $email["Email"]."\n";
}
```

Connexion to database works fine.

Comment: You only get one row because you only call `fetch()` once.

Comment: *"Connexion to database works fine."* - Which is what, MySQLi_ or PDO? Both have `fetch()`. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php and http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php

Comment: PDO but it was fetchALL that i needed to use. Thank you.

Comment: @magentonewbie Ok. I had to be sure as it could have swung either way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use `fetchALL()` as `fetch()` only [returns one row](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php) according to the docs:

> **Fetches a row** from a result set associated with a PDOStatement object.

```
$query = "SELECT Email from client";
$result = $db->query($query)->fetchALL();
foreach($result as $email){
    echo $email["Email"]."\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `fetch()` function only fetches one record.

Modify your code like this:

```
$query = "SELECT Email from client";
$res = $db->query($query);
while($result = $res->fetch()){
    echo $result["Email"]."\n";
}
```